# Open a URL in Epiphany from Python Script on RPi2

Tags: python, terminal, midori

So I am trying to open a URL in Epiphany WebBrowser [ let's say for example `http://www.google.com` ] from a python script. My python script is as follows:

```
import os
string = "DISPLAY=:0 xdg-open http://www.google.com"
os.system(string)
```

It returns the error: `xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://www.google.com'`

However if I type `DISPLAY=:0 xdg-open http://www.google.com` into LXTerminal is works fine. It also works remotely through SSH.

Any Ideas? Also can someone explain to me why a command works fine in terminal, but not when you try to call them from a Python script using `os.system()`?

**UPDATE -- NEED HELP STILL**

**NOTE:** All files are located in `/home/pi`

After much frustration, I figured I would give the below method a try. I created a file called `google.sh`. The code for `google.sh` s as follows:

```
#google.sh    
DISPLAY=:0 xdg-open http://www.google.com
```

when I call upon this program using `./google.sh` from LXTerminal it works fine! **Great** so now let's call it from a python script called `test.py` whose code is as follows:

```
# test.py
import os

string = "/home/pi/google.sh"
os.system(string)
```

However for some reason it STILL returns: `xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://www.google.com'`

Answer (score 0):

how about this?
the idea, is to open a epiphany window and close it after 5 seconds.

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep

p = subprocess.Popen("exec epiphany-browser http://yahoo.com", stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
sleep(5)
p.kill()
print("done")
```